# Creating a randomly generated triangle and drawing it to a Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, random, geometry, awt

I'm having some big trouble getting java's swing and awt libraries (first time working with them) to work correctly for me. Basically, I want to make a randomly generated triangle and then display it on a JPanel. I've been working on it for a while, but I can't seem to make the triangle show up.

I have a RandomTriangle class that is like so:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class RandomTriangle {

  private Random rand = new Random();

  private int x1, y1,     // Coordinates
              x2, y2,
              x3, y3;
  private double a, b, c; // Sides

  public RandomTriangle(int limit) {
    do { // make sure that no points are on the same line
      x1 = rand.nextInt(limit);
      y1 = rand.nextInt(limit);

      x2 = rand.nextInt(limit);
      y2 = rand.nextInt(limit);

      x3 = rand.nextInt(limit);
      y3 = rand.nextInt(limit);
    } while (!((x2 - x1) * (y3 - y1) == (y2 - y1) * (x3 - x1)));

    a = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2 - x1), 2) + Math.pow((y2 - y1), 2));
    b = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x3 - x2), 2) + Math.pow((y3 - y2), 2));
    c = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x1 - x3), 2) + Math.pow((y1 - y3), 2));
  }


  public int[] getXCoordinates() {
    int[] coordinates = {this.x1, this.x2, this.x3};
    return coordinates;
  }

  public int[] getYCoordinates() {
    int[] coordinates = {this.y1, this.y2, this.y3};
    return coordinates;
  }
}
```

And I then I have a SimpleTriangles class that extends JPanel:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SimpleTriangles extends JPanel {

  public SimpleTriangles() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Draw triangle in JPanel");  
    frame.add(this);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    frame.setSize(400,400);  
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
    frame.setVisible(true);  
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint( g );
    RandomTriangle myTriangle = new RandomTriangle(150);
    int[] x = myTriangle.getXCoordinates();
    int[] y = myTriangle.getYCoordinates();

    g.setColor(new Color(255,192,0));
    g.fillPolygon(x, y, 3);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    RandomTriangle myTriangle = new RandomTriangle(300);
    for (int x : myTriangle.getXCoordinates())
      System.out.println(x);
    for (int y : myTriangle.getYCoordinates())
      System.out.println(y);

    SimpleTriangles st = new SimpleTriangles(); 
  }
}
```

Is there anything that I'm doing horribly wrong? Like I said, this is my first time messing with GUI in Java, so I may be very well off. When I run this, I get a grey, blank JPanel. However, if I specify the coordinates explicitly, such as `int[]x={0,150,300};` etc, I get a triangle.

Thank you!

Comment: Use paintComponent(...) not paint(...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your formula for ensuring that no points are on the same line doesn't ensure that 2 points lie on the same line. More often than not there are at least 2 co-linear points. You can avoid this by using:

```
   ...
   } while (((x2 - x1) * (y3 - y1) == (y2 - y1) * (x3 - x1)));
```

Comment: That worked! But could you briefly elaborate on why it worked? I don't think I completely understand.

Answer (score 4):

> *Could you briefly elaborate on why it worked?*

The predicate `p = ((x2 - x1) * (y3 - y1) == (y2 - y1) * (x3 - x1))` is `true` when the three points are [collinear](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Collinear.html).

Your [`while`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) statement, `while (!p)`, exits the `do` loop only when three collinear points are found.

In contrast, @Reimeus' statement, `while (p)`, exits the `do` loop only when a valid triangle is found.